# Referenced file contains error at Liberty server.xml file

Tags: eclipse, websphere, websphere-liberty

I am receiving the following error at server.xml file liberty server. I couldn't solve this problem.

**Referenced file contains errors (file:/D:/workspaces/myprojects/.metadata/.plugins/com.ibm.ws.st.core/Liberty Runtime/server.xsd). For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and
select "Show Details..."**

**My server.xsd file **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ext="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/dde/schema/annotation/ext"> 
    <xsd:complexType name="com.ibm.ws.app.manager.webappcfg"> 
        <xsd:annotation> 
            <xsd:documentation>Defines the properties of a web application.</xsd:documentation> 
            <xsd:appinfo> 
                <ext:label>Web Application</ext:label> 
            </xsd:appinfo> 
        </xsd:annotation> 
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> 
            <xsd:element name="startAfter" type="com.ibm.ws.app.manager-factory"> 
                <xsd:annotation> 
                    <xsd:documentation>Specifies applications that are required to start before this application can begin starting. </xsd:documentation> 
                    <xsd:appinfo> 
                        <ext:label>Start After</ext:label> 
                    </xsd:appinfo> 
                </xsd:annotation> 
            </xsd:element> 
            <xsd:element name="classloader" type="com.ibm.ws.classloading.classloader"> 
            .
            .
            .
```

I want to get rid of this error.

Error Details:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDif2.png)

Comment: Did you Show Details? What was shown?

Comment: I hid the error by changing xml validation setting -> Windows -> preferences -> XML -> XML files -> validation -> Referenced file contains error but I still wonder solution. There is no details button it is just a text.

Comment: Yes, and like the message says, right-click on it to get the menu where you have the option to show details.

Comment: ohh sorry okay I added to question

Comment: Thank you for adding the image.    Would you also be able to paste the contents of your server.xsd file around the line mentioned in the problem (line 4943)?   I can't find a "minLength" in the instances of server.xsd that I'm looking at.  Thank you.

Comment: None of the reported errors' line numbers are shown in the part of the `server.xsd` you've added.

Comment: Server.xsd file has big amount of line. I am adding 4943 line ->                             <xsd:minLength value="-1">

Comment: Can you add a bit more context than that, eg. share the complete element or type definition this is part of?  Or share the whole file in a GitHub  gist maybe?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nurullahpolat0/9d7ac1e7869cf67ac05eb924108f51aa

Comment: I shared my server.xsd file thanks for your helps

Comment: Also I am using Eclipse  Version: 4.7.3.v20180301-0715 (IBM rational applicaiton developer 9.7.0) and I am using liberty 22 and I am using spring boot 2.7.8

Comment: OK, it does look like the server.xsd has a bug in it.  FWIW, when I tried generating the XSD from newer versions of Liberty and newer versions of tooling this problem seemed to not occur.  Let me think about what to suggest next.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in Rational Application Developer.

A broad set of options would be something like:

1. Open up a support case against this product, (assuming you have a support contract, etc.).
2. If you are unconcerned with maintaining a supported product installation, it might be technically possible to install a similar feature set by installing [Liberty Developer Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-liberty-developer-tools) (previously known as "WebSphere Developer Tools") from the Eclipse Marketplace.  A typical Eclipse installation makes it fairly transparent what it is installed, so this might not be too much of a "hack", but it's conceivable it could negate your ability to get support going forwards.  (I'm just giving a general warning.  I'm not claiming any knowledge about your specific circumstances).   Assuming this is an option for you, I would experiment in a new, separate install rather than an install I was already relying on.
3. If you are just interested in developing Jakarta EE and MicroProfile applications on Open Liberty / WebSphere Liberty, and not the specific toolset you asked about from RAD (or LDT/WDT), you might take a look at our new [Liberty Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/liberty-tools) still in "Early Release".

Apologies if it's a bit of a stretch to point to totally different features (components), but there is an analogous generation of the server.xml XSD in each of 2. and 3., and I do believe this particular issue does not exist (or has been fixed) in each of these options.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and following fixed it (it was mentioned on comments). RAD's server.xsd is old and need to be regenarated with current one.

1. Regenerate it:

   cd C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\bin\tools
   java -jar ws-schemagen.jar C:\server.xsd
2. Replace in RAD's Liberty folder:
   ...IBM\rationalsdp\myworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.ibm.ws.st.core\Liberty Runtime